# Why do equal expressions in 'class' and 'main' behave differently?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

```
 class Class {
  public:
   std::pair<int,int> p (45, 12);// error: "requires a type specifier"
  };

 int main(){
    std::pair<int, int> pm (45, 12);// ok
 }
```

'utility' header was included. Also if I try to create a pair through 'make_pair' the compiler writes "identificator "make_pair" is not defined", but it's defined in "utility", isn't it?

Comment: These are not expression but definitions. The first is a member variable declaration with (wrong) initialization. The second is the definition of a local variable. That's a difference.

Comment: You can't use parentheses when doing inline initialization in classes, to disambiguate from function declarations. Either use "assignment" syntax with `=`, or use uniform initialization with curly braces `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

An informal answer if I may. The two statements are very different beasts. The first one is a member variable declaration with an attempt at initialisation.

The second is the declaration of a variable with automatic storage duration, again with initialisation.

This mess was cleared up in C++11 with *uniform initialisation*:

```
std::pair<int,int> p{45, 12};
```

will work in either case. Note the brace syntax.